# iMovie for OS X removed from OS X?

Tags: macos, imovie

I had already installed iMovie on my Mac. Now after some months I wanted to create a new movie, but I couldn't find iMovie in OS X again.

When I look in the App Store I can see iMovie available now for $15.

Now I am very confused. Could it really be that Apple uninstalled iMovie and now I have to pay for it? Or is this a different version?

Comment: Did you use Spotlight to search for iMovie on your Mac? If it is not there, are you logged into the App Store with the same Apple ID you used when you initially purchased the application?

Comment: 1. How exactly (details please) did you install iMovie in the first place? 
2. Have you checked the Applications folder (in Finder: press Cmd-Shift-A) as well as the Applications folder within your user home folder  (press Cmd-Shift-H to open the home folder)?
3. Have you searched for 'iMovie' via the Spotlight search (top right-hand corner of the screen)?

Answer (score 1):

Apps don't disappear automatically. If you have iMovie '11 (version 9.x, gold + dark grey icon), the Mac AppStore will show the current version of iMovie (version 10.x, purple-coloured icon) as a new item because Apple charges for major version *upgrades* (e.g., version 9.x to 10.x), unless the user has a voucher from purchasing a new Mac.